# How do I Convert CGI to WSGI?

Tags: python, apache, cgi, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I inherited a code base that uses CGI scripts. From what I read they're inefficient because they fork a new process every time a request comes in. I'm currently attempting to convert them to WSGI but I'm confused on the following:

1. How are WSGI and CGI different code-wise? I know that the application must be callable but other than that, I'm not sure on what else I will have to do to change it.
2. How do I benchmark the increase in efficiency that I read should be obvious with the change?

Other info that might be useful would be that I'm going to be using Apache and mod_wsgi.

Let me know if there's any other info I can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some ways wsgi abstracts out some of the stuff cgi does into a pure python function call, with no side effects.

The "inputs" to a cgi program are the process environment, in `os.environ` and `sys.stdin`.  The output to such a program is `sys.stdout`, with errors reaching the server log from `sys.stderr`.

A wsgi application is a python function taking two* arguments, usually called `environ` (which will be a `dict`) and `start_response` (which will be another function).

The first argument is a `dict`, containing all of the things a cgi program would get in `os.environ`, but it also contains a couple of extra keys.  Notably, it contains `"wsgi.input"`, a file-like object which takes the place of `sys.stdin` for the purposes of request body.

A cgi program uses `sys.stdout` for both the HTTP response line, response headers, and response body.  In a wsgi program, the first two are passed as arguments to the `start_response` argument.  A wsgi response body is not** written to a file;  instead, it's returned from the app function.

A typical CGI program might look like this:

```
import os, sys
request_size = int(os.environ.get("HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH", "0"))
person = sys.stdin.read(request_size)

response = "Hello %s!\n" % person
print "Status: 200 OK"
print "Content-Type: text/plain"
print "Content-Length: %d" % len(response)
print
print response
```

The equivalent wsgi program would look like:

```
def myApp(environ, start_response):
    request_size = int(environ.get("HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH", "0"))
    wsgi_input = environ.get("wsgi.input")
    person = wsgi_input.read(request_size) if request_size and wsgi_input else ""
    response = "Hello %s!\n" % person

    start_response("200 OK",
        [("Content-Type", "text/plain"),
         ("Content-Length", str(len(response)))]

    return [response]
```

---

<sub>* for technical reasons, there's an optional, third argument, mostly for "middleware"</sub>
<sub>** for compatability with old web frameworks, start_response() returns a file-like object that can be written to, but this is not recommended.  In your case it *might* simplify the conversion, but since an invasive change is needed anyway, see if you can avoid it.</sub>